# gerar um pdf somente com os argumentos passado por um form Django

Tags: python, aplicação-web, django, django-rest-framework

Ola, estou tendo um problema ao gerar um pdf, preciso criar filtros para um report mais detalhado, meu código consiste de uma view simples de Template aonde montei o formulário com o metodo "GET", e uma função aonde o meu pdf é gerado. o problema é que os filtros que seleciono no TemplateView nao passa para a função de pdf. alguma dica? desde já agradeço.

**view da criação do formulario**

```
class SolicitacaoReport(PermissionRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    permission_required = 'administrativo_permissao'
    raise_exception = True
    template_name='administrativo/home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SolicitacaoReport, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['usuarios'] = User.objects.select_related().order_by('username')
        context['departamentos'] = Departamento.objects.select_related().order_by('nome_departamento')
        return context
```

**view da criação do pdf**

```
def solicitacao_report(request):
    resp = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')

    if request.method == 'GET':
        user = request.GET.get('usuario')
        data_emissao = request.GET.get('departamento_relacionamento')


    solicitacoes = Solicitacao.objects.order_by('user', 'data_emissao', 'departamento_relacionamento')
    report = SolicitacaoListReport(queryset=solicitacoes)
    report.generate_by(PDFGenerator, filename=resp)

    return resp
```

**formulário html.**

```
<form method="GET" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row mx-auto">
            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Usuário</p>
                    <select class="form-control" id="usuarios" name='usuario'>
                        <option>--------</option>
                        {% for usuario in usuarios %}
                         <option>{{usuario.name}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Numero Requisição</p>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="requisicao" placeholder="N°" name='requisicaoForm'>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Data De</p>
                    <input id="dateDe" placeholder="00/00/0000" name='dataDe' />    
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Departamento</p>
                    <select class="form-control" id="usuarios" name='departamentoForm'>
                        <option>--------</option>
                        {% for departamento in departamentos %}
                        <option>{{departamento.nome_departamento}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Ate</p>
                    <input id="dateATE" placeholder="00/00/0000" name='dataAte' />  
                </div>
            </div>                  
        </div>
    <dir>
        <a class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" href="{% url 'teste' %}">Imprimir</a>
    </dir>
</form>
```

> sou novo em web então estou preso nisso a um bom tempinho já, agradeço
>   desde já a ajuda
>
> estou usando o Geraldo Reports do marinho brandão atualizado pelo Thiago Pena para rodar no python 3

**EDIT**

já estou conseguindo pegar as informações e usá-las na função o problema que mesmo recebendo os valores do GET o filtro ainda não funciona.

***View's***

```
class SolicitacaoReport(PermissionRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
permission_required = 'administrativo_permissao'
raise_exception = True
template_name='administrativo/home.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['usuarios'] = User.objects.select_related().order_by('username')
    context['departamentos'] = Departamento.objects.select_related().order_by('nome_departamento')
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

***função que recebe os dados e gera o pdf***

```
def solicitacao_report(request):
resp = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')

if request.method == 'GET':
    user = request.GET.get("usuario")
    data_emissao = request.GET.get("departamento_relacionamento")


solicitacoes = Solicitacao.objects.order_by('user', 'data_emissao', 'departamento_relacionamento')

if user:
    solicitacoes.filter(user=user)

report = SolicitacaoListReport(queryset=solicitacoes)
report.generate_by(PDFGenerator, filename=resp)

return resp
```

no html fiz uma alteração trocando o a href para um input com type submit e passei a url para o action do form.

a url de direcionamento fica assim quando seleciono uma opção no filtro e dou o submit

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/solicitacao/administrativo/sistema/resumo/filtros/pdf?csrfmiddlewaretoken=7Pcb4f20M5maPHYmED3tTSXmVDY2m62iR6MfXYJzZn3syONTASVVZ0cQ6D0NRYdS&usuario=1&requisicaoForm=&dataDe=&departamentoForm=--------&dataAte=

como pode ver na url ele traz o id do meu usuário o problema que mesmo pegando as informações com o GET não consigo usá-las para fazer o filtro

Comment: Estou achando um pouco obscuro sua questão. Qual é o seu problema? o que esta dando errado? O que vc quer? Em resumo seria: Obter dados de um form e trata-los? No caso montar um pdf com esses dados, é isso?

Comment: isso é isso mesmo, desculpe quis dar uma explicação mais detalhada e acabei fazendo o oposto.

Comment: Ok, veja se consegue com minha resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc teria muito mais flexibilidade se utilizasse os [forms do proprio django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/topics/forms/), ai voce poderia continuar usando as templateview ou mesmo as [formsviews](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView), mas vou considerar nessa reposta o que vc ja esta utilizando.

Como vc precisa manipular varios dados advindos do form, o ideal seria utilizar o metodo `POST` ao invés do `GET`, get seria interessante para uma requisição de conulta, por exemplo. Vc pode ver um resumo [aqui](https://blog.alura.com.br/diferencas-entre-get-e-post/). Utilizando o POST, mude sua view para algo mais ou menos assim:

```
class SolicitacaoReport(PermissionRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    permission_required = 'administrativo_permissao'
    raise_exception = True
    template_name='administrativo/home.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        # Daqui para frente trate o contexto da forma que for necessario,
        # Exemplo: context['usuario'] => Nome do usuario

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SolicitacaoReport, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['usuarios'] = User.objects.select_related().order_by('username')
        context['departamentos'] = Departamento.objects.select_related().order_by('nome_departamento')
        return context
```

Veja que o override do metodo `post`, "captura" os dados contidos no `request`, vc terá um dicionário com chaves/valores dos dados enviados pelo form, voce pode, então, trata-los na própria `view` ou manda-lo para um outro método, uma lib, etc.

Comment: a primeira parte deu certo consegui pegar os dados do formulário, o problema que agora estou recebendo um erro quando redireciono para a função.

Comment: AttributeError at /solicitacao/administrativo/sistema/resumo/filtros/pdf

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Como assim "redireciona para a função"? se vc tem os dados pode fazer o que quiser com eles na propria view. Edit a pergunta e coloque a nova versão ou faça outra pergunta com esse novo problema.

Comment: blz, editei a pergunta colocando o progresso que fiz até agora.

Comment: conseguiiii !!!!! tava bobeando no if da função estava passando o parâmetro porem não passava aonde ele armazenava... ai não vai mesmo né hahaha.